# Error while saving a matplotlib animation, missing 'dpi' argument

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, ffmpeg

I'm trying to save an animation of matplotlib.animation.AnimationFunc and I get an error saying 'dpi' argument missing. Obviously, I have the dpi set so I don't understand where this error comes from.

I'm running python 3.6 and matplotlib 3.0.3, I also just installed ffmpeg from ubuntu official repositories (Ubuntu 18.04).

This is the part of my code that should affect that, although I think it should be something of the system:

```
Writer = writers['ffmpeg']
writer = Writer(fps=15, metadata=dict(artist='Me'), bitrate=1800,)
ani = FuncAnimation(fig, anime, interval=time_step *
                    10**3, frames=F, repeat=False,) 
ani.save('standard_map.mp4', writer=Writer, dpi=100)
```

The errors is:

```
with writer.saving(self._fig, filename, dpi):
File "/usr/lib/python3.6/contextlib.py", line 159, in helper
    return _GeneratorContextManager(func, args, kwds)
File "/usr/lib/python3.6/contextlib.py", line 60, in __init__
    self.gen = func(*args, **kwds) TypeError: saving() missing 1 required positional argument: 'dpi'
```

I tried both adding the lines they suggested there and the error stills the same.

```
plt.rcParams['animation.ffmpeg_path'] = '/usr/bin/ffmpeg'
```

I also tried changing the writer to 'imagemagick' the one set on Ubuntu by default and the error persists.

Comment: It's funny, how many people (including me) got and overlooked the same mistake. You have to pass the `writer` with the lowercase, not the uppercase `w`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no dpi parameter passed to `ani.save()`, provide it:

```
ani.save('standard_map.mp4', writer=Writer, dpi=100)
```

Comment: That doesn't make any change, I've tried before and the error is the same. The thing is I checked the code and it takes the one from rcParams if you don't define it. Anyway I edited the post with the parameter in order not to fall to this same answer.

Comment: Yes the thing is the error actually says that. That's why I'm not understanding why it fails if I'm passing it. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: nice mistery indeed, looking into it since not familiar with Ubuntu

Comment: Not working either. I tried to change the writer to other ones Ubuntu had by default and the error stills the same so I think it is not related with the ffmepg format. (I'll write it on the issue)

Comment: Was anyone able to find a solution?

Comment: I couldn't find anything, hopefully OP did :)

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
writer = animation.FFMpegFileWriter(fps=15, metadata=dict(artist='Me'), bitrate=1800)
```

For MACOS you need the `blit=False`.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reproduce the problem using the example from the matplotlib documentation:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation
import matplotlib.animation as animation

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
xdata, ydata = [], []
ln, = plt.plot([], [], 'ro')

def init():
    ax.set_xlim(0, 2*np.pi)
    ax.set_ylim(-1, 1)
    return ln,

def update(frame):
    xdata.append(frame)
    ydata.append(np.sin(frame))
    ln.set_data(xdata, ydata)
    return ln,

writers = animation.writers
writer = writers['ffmpeg']
ani = FuncAnimation(fig, update, frames=np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 128),
                    init_func=init, blit=True)
ani.save("test.mp4",writer=writer)
```

This will indeed give you the exception from above:

```py
TypeError: saving() missing 1 required positional argument: 'dpi'
```

There's an easy solution: You need an instance of the writer rather than the writer class itself. Thus replace

```py
writer = writers['ffmpeg']
```

with

```py
writer = writers['ffmpeg']()
```

Answer (score 0):

From this [guide](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/animation/basic_example_writer_sgskip.html).

To write to file, you should use the *Agg* backend for matplotlib.

Put the following at the top of your code.

```
matplotlib.use("Agg")
```